# Vertical-align to the top multiple divs with same width, not height. With no "rows"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to `vertical-align` to the top all my items. With no "rows". Like this :

[image: result]

I used some `flexbox` attributes but with no luck. This is what i have now :

[image: what i have]

I found a "non-perfect" solution that works (http://jsfiddle.net/Lstgwmgb/) but this solution needs to use additional divs, so the responsive don't work, and you have to use JS to put them equaly on blue columns (watch below)

[image: non perfect solution]

Comment: You can't do that with `flexbox`, you need i.e Masonry ... or give it a try using float

Comment: Or use columns - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns

Comment: Didn't know Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com) I will give a try after trying with "floats". Thanks you @LGSon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I got stuck at the same so I switched to `jquery` to achieve this.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/h00t6vw5/)

Here is the code:

```js
var $boxes;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $boxes = $(".box");
  setupColumns();
  $(window).on("resize", setupColumns);
});

function setupColumns() {
  var $columnwrapper = $("#columns");
  //////////start change////////////
  var dummy = $("<div>").addClass("column");
  dummy.appendTo($columnwrapper); // add it to wrapper so that it gets displayed
  var w = dummy.width(); // this now returns 114
  dummy.remove(); // now that we have got the width, remove it

  // just to be on safer side:
  if (w == 0) {
    console.log("column width is 0.");
    return;
  }

  //////////end change////////////
  var cnt = Math.floor($columnwrapper.width() / w);
  var cols = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    var $col = $("<div>").addClass("column");
    cols.push($col);
  }
  $columnwrapper.append(cols);
  var cnt = 0;
  $boxes.each(function() {
    $(this).detach().appendTo(cols[cnt]);
    cnt = (cnt + 1) % cols.length;
  });
}
```

```css
.column {
  width: 114px;
  float: left
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns"></div>
<div class="box" style="height:100px">HELLO WORLD 1</div>
<div class="box" style="height:120px">HELLO WORLD 2</div>
<div class="box" style="height:70px">HELLO WORLD 3</div>
<div class="box" style="height:90px">HELLO WORLD 4</div>
<div class="box" style="height:170px">HELLO WORLD 5</div>
<div class="box" style="height:70px">HELLO WORLD 6</div>
<div class="box" style="height:50px">HELLO WORLD 7</div>
<div class="box" style="height:70px">HELLO WORLD 8</div>
<div class="box" style="height:80px">HELLO WORLD 9</div>
<div class="box">HELLO WORLD 10</div>
```

Comment: It work fines, i wanted a solution without JS, but it seems impossible now. Thanks you